# WINAPI: Disable inheritance of stdin stdout stderr handles

Tags: c++, winapi, subprocess

I have created child process with CreateProcess with flag `BOOL bInheritHandles = TRUE` as I want to pass some handles to anonymous pipes to child process.

I have **NOT** setted `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput` and `hStdErro`r and a `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag in `STARTUPINFO` struct, since i dont want to do something with childs stdout and etc.

but child process seems to inherit handles to console buffers and its output goes straight into parent app console. i want to pervent this, so I used 
`SetHandleInformation(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);`
wich reports error 87 - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Beyond the error, your code doesn't make any sense. You are retrieving the standard output handle and setting a flag indicating that child processes should inherit this object handle. That already happens, you don't need to call any function to make it work. It certainly will not "disable child process output to console".

Comment: Perhaps it would help to examine [the sample provided as part of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)?

Comment: added more details, I have looked into sample in documentation and I want exactly oppose thing, that it suggests.

Comment: Either I am unable to read at this late hour, or your question still makes little sense. You say that you want to disable inheritance of the standard handles, yet you are setting `bInheritHandles` to true and trying to indicate that the `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` should be inherited. I don't understand what your goal is.

Comment: standart handles should **NOT** be inherited. but some other should. There is 0 in third param of `SetHandleInformation`, same as in example from documentation, when they are disabled inheriting of some handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you cannot set `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` for the standard output handle.

Instead you should create the process passing either the `DETACHED_PROCESS` or `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` creation flags. Or if you don't want the child process to use a different console, you'll need to supply standard handles in the `STARTUPINFO` struct.

Comment: Bah, now it ignores `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag and spawns new window. this behavior in unacceptable. I guess I need to alocate some console buffer myself and pass it somehow to child process?

Comment: Hard to know what the solution is if we don't have the problem at hand.

Comment: Its hard to describe it either. I'm writing a small library for our project which allows to create child processes and connect them with pipes (named and not). So I must handle situations where standart handles must be passed to some pipe and when they should not be. I guess I have to stuff standart handles of child process in `STARTUPINFO` with handles to `nul` device when I dont need any of them.

Comment: Ty everyone. I've got my answer. Language barrier does not make it better